# iOS - Play audio file while WebRTC video/audio is playing

Tags: ios, audio, webrtc

I successfully implemented WebRTC in my app however I was having an issue where the audio would come out from the receiver and not the receiver + speaker. I ended up modifying a solution I found to handle audio routing when plugging in and out bluetooth headsets or regular headsets.
The notification typically fires as soon as I receive audio via the WebRTC library.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: routeChange)


  func routeChange(_ n: Notification) {
    guard let info = n.userInfo,
        let value = info[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt,
        let reason = AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason(rawValue: value) else { return }
    switch reason {
    case .categoryChange:
        for description in AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs {
            if description.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.builtInSpeaker || description.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.builtInReceiver {
                try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
            }
        }
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

However this solution prevented me from playing an audio file that I use as a cue/feedback when the user taps a button in my app. Basically, the following code will play the audio file but it will mess up the configuration I have above in various ways. It will primarily make the audio come out of the receiver instead of both the speaker and the receiver. I believe it also messed with headsets.

```
private func playTapSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: App.AudioFile.tapFeedback, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

    guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

    player.play()

} catch let error {
    print("### Error - playing tap audio -", error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

I need to play the audio file without affecting the routeChange method.

Comment: hello. to play the audio stream from webRTC also needs to be played with media player? can u help me with that?

Comment: same issue here. did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @Tarek , I've got the same issue. First I change the audio output route to speaker, then I play the video file, and audio comes from receiver instead of the speaker. But changing the output route to speaker second time, during the video playback, activates speaker mode. Did you solve your issue? Most probably it is the same issue that I've got.

Comment: @Fury did you solve this problem?